# Microsoft Graph API get task list without user login

Tags: python, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to create a python script that adds some tasks to my Microsoft ToDo List by using the Microsoft Graph API from python.

So far I was able to achieve this such that every time I run the script I have to log into my account and give permission such that the script can access my tasks.

However, I now want to achieve the same result but without having to log into my account every time.

My script looks as follows

```py
import msal
import requests

client_id = '....'
client_secret = '....'
authority = 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/....'
scope = ['https://graph.microsoft.com/.default']

client = msal.ConfidentialClientApplication(client_id, authority=authority, client_credential=client_secret)

# First, try to lookup an access token in cache
token_result = client.acquire_token_silent(scope, account=None)

# If the token is available in cache, save it to a variable
if token_result:
  access_token = 'Bearer ' + token_result['access_token']
  print('Access token was loaded from cache')

# If the token is not available in cache, acquire a new one from Azure AD and save it to a variable
if not token_result:
  token_result = client.acquire_token_for_client(scopes=scope)
  access_token = 'Bearer ' + token_result['access_token']
#   print('New access token was acquired from Azure AD')

# print(access_token)


url = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/ae294107-3a57-448f-be95-f58390836cca/todo/lists'
headers = {
    'Authorization': access_token
}

graph_result = requests.get(url=url, headers=headers)

print(graph_result.json())
```

By using this script I do not have to log in every time. However I can only access my user information but not my task list.

Is there a possibility to access my task lists without having to log in every time?

Answer (score 0):

In that case you need to use ROPC flow and hard-code the username and password in the back-end code. please follow the doc - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth-ropc

Hope this helps
Thanks

Comment: As far as I can tell this flow does not work if I use multi factor authentication for my account. Do you happen to know a similar flow wich also allows me to keep the multi factor authentication for my account?